# Queryset Union in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to do a simple double entry accounting with Django. Every transaction is currently one object with debit and credit accounts being foreign keys. Now I'm trying to get all transaction objects out so that there's debit and credit object for every transaction and I can easily order and represent every account's transactions and totals in the template. So every transaction object needs to have debit object and credit object in the final outcome. I think in MySQL you could achieve this with something like:

```
SELECT date, description, amount, debit_account AS account, debit AS 1 FROM Transaction
UNION
SELECT date, description, amount, credit_account AS account, debit AS 0 FROM Transaction
```

What is the right way to do this with Python's objects in Django? Union seems to override the changes within the for loop I currently have and I end up with no distinction between debit and credit.

```
models.py

class Transaction(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    debit_account = models.ForeignKey('ledger.Account', related_name='debit_account', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    credit_account = models.ForeignKey('ledger.Account', related_name='credit_account', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    debit_in_ledger = models.BooleanField(default=False)


views.py

def ledger(request):

    transaction_list_debit = Transaction.objects.all()
    transaction_list_credit = Transaction.objects.all()

    for a in transaction_list_debit:
        a.debit_in_ledger = True

    transaction_list = transaction_list_debit.union(transaction_list_credit, all=True).order_by('debit_account', 'public_date')

    return render(request, 'pages/ledger.html', {'transaction_list' : transaction_list})
```

Comment: You probably meant `1 AS debit` instead of `debit AS 1`?

Comment: Furthermore what should this queryset contain? Dictionaries? `Transaction` objects? Why do you add a `debit_in_ledger` field here if you want to set it dynamically (in other words, is this a "persistent" column, or just something you added to pass `True` and `False` values from a query)?

Comment: You are right with 1 AS debit. I would prefer if the queryset contained Transaction objects. The debit_in_ledger was created just for trying to make the necessary distinction to the final outcome and not really needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, F, Value

q1 = Transaction.objects.annotate(
    account = F('debit_account')
    debit = Value(True, output_field=BooleanField())
)

q2 = Transaction.objects.annotate(
    account = F('credit_account')
    debit = Value(False, output_field=BooleanField())
)

qs = q1 | q2
```

where `qs` is thus our "final" queryset. This `QuerySet` will contain `Transaction` objects, and *every* `Transaction` object in the queryset will have *two* extra attributes: `account` and `debit`. Note that other attributes like `debit_account`, etc. will still exist. Furthermore every *real* `Transaction` in the database will thus occur *twice*: once from `q1`, and once from `q2`.

Furthermore the `.account` will contain the *primary* key of the related `Account`, so not a reference to the `Account`. You can then fetch the `Account` with `Account.objects.get(pk=some_transaction.account)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Got it working just the way I wanted.